# Deleted post possible to recover?

Tags: facebook-pages

Is it possible to recover a post that I deleted by mistake?  It was my own post that I wrote.  It appeared twice on my timeline and I was just trying to delete one.  Obviously I did something wrong because they both disappeared. This happened just one day ago.   I would like to get it back.

Answer (score -1):

[image] please recover my Facebook page Apna bakakhel news . I made a mistake, please restore my page again.